# How to post facebook post to users timeline ,who are like the application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page tab application, and a list of users who like the page.
And am having the access tokens for each users who allow my application.

How can I post to their wall via the application?

Comment: You need to expand your question - at least demonstrate some effort by showing the code you have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liking a page does not give that page permission to post via API to your wall. It'd be horribly abused by spammy pages. What you want to do is not possible.